# How to automatically increase the width of a textarea while text is typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, textarea

I am trying to build a textarea whose width will dynamically increase while inserting text.

I have found many scripts that would dynamically resize a textarea by changing it's height but nothing that meets my needs.

So do you know anything that could help ?

Comment: ive tried to use stuff like this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrowtextarea  , but what i only get is vertical expansion of the textarea

Comment: You need to modify one of these scripts to change the width instead of the height.

Comment: So have you actually tried to write your own horizontal width expansion plugin? There are tutorials on how to write your own vertical expander (such as [this one](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-2/)) that should be pretty easy to adapt for horizontal expansion. I have to question the usefulness of this, however. Why do you want the textarea to expand horizontally? That would just be plain annoying, IMO.

Comment: no actually it's exactly what i need and since i don t have much time it 'd be much better to find an existing plugin. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the textarea an ID. If the font inside the textarea is monospace is simple. If not is a bit complicated (create a distribution function of the width of a character, get an average use it forward).

On a onkeyup or onkeypressed event use something like

```
if (document.getElementById('yourid').value.lenght>defaultValue)
{
    defaultValue = defaultValue+charWidth;
    document.getElementById('yourid').width = (defaultValue+charWidth)+'px';       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this may help..

```
<textarea id="tarea" onkeypress="change()" style="width:200;"> </textarea>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
function change() {
    var a = document.getElementById('tarea');
    var len = a.value.length;
    a.style.width = 200 + len;
    alert(a.style.width);
}
</script>
```

have a good day..